# Show Rows Data Into Column Wise

Tags: postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, crosstab

i wants to show rows data into columns. suppose if rows type increased then number of columns also increased. Information as follow:

[Please see picture to get idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rnlb.gif)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513208/postgresql-query-with-dynamic-columns-and-counts-from-join and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223256/combining-multiple-rows-into-one and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgresql and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456734/dynamic-pivot-for-thousands-of-columns just to name a few

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT` with `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT t.Name AS Type,
       COUNT(*) AS NumberOfCase,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Name = 'Resolved' THEN 1 END) AS Resolved,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Name = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) AS Pending,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Name = 'Waiting' THEN 1 END) AS Waiting
FROM Type t
LEFT JOIN "Case" c
  ON c.CaseType = t.TypeId
LEFT JOIN "Status" s
  ON c.CaseStatus = s.StatusId
GROUP BY t.Name;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4b40a/1/0)**</kbd>